# Store the Firebase token in database

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

On token Refresh generate the Refresh token and store in database when the application is Installed.

Token Generated Code:

```
[Service]

[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService 
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    //string refreshedToken;
    private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {

       var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
       Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);            
    }}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: which database the local SQLite database? or do you need to push it to the server using some API?

Comment: You need to push the token to your server, with any other details like user id.

Comment: only store the token in sql server.add the token in sql server only when the App is installed.
but  the app is launched every time doesn't store it on Sql Server.yes i need to push it to server.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`SqlConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection?view=netframework-4.7.2) Class in `SendRegistrationToServer()` method to connect to your sql server.

For example:

```
    void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(yourconnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1 (id, token) VALUES('1', '" + token + "')", connection);
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```